# Is there a key combination to get the "classic logon screen" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, login-screen

Pre-Windows 7 we can press CTRL+ALT+DEL to get the User+Password dialog (a.k.a. classic logon screen).

Is there a key combination to get this "classic logon screen" from the default logon screen (i.e. the "Welcome screen" that shows the different users available that you click and then enter a password)?

Note: I simply want a key combination to get the classic logon dialog. I do not want to configure the system to use the classic logon logon via secpol.msc or gpedit.msc.

Comment: Why?  Where is the application in adding extra steps to actually log in?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the enter or space can be used instead of clicking the mouse.

Comment: too many users in the logon screen... also I like (and used very much) the shortcut to the logon dialog and prefer it... there are also other reasons but I believe the above are sufficient....

Comment: Do you want to get a command prompt like log-on window?

Comment: I haven't used windows 7 in some time, but I seem to recall getting to that screen by holding ctrl+alt and hitting del twice. I don't have a way of testing it at this moment.

Comment: Yes Biswa... I want to call the user+password dialog from the welcome screen (the one that shows the users icons)

Comment: nop nullmeta... that does not work...

Comment: nop nulmeta... that do not work... I wish... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Vista and later, the only way to access the Classic logon prompt is by enabling it through Group Policy.

According to the Wikipedia article [List of features removed in Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_Vista#User_accounts_and_Winlogon), the ability to access the classic logon prompt by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> twice was removed starting with Vista:

> Although classic logon and Ctrl+Alt+Del enforcement can be enabled through Group Policy, the classic logon prompt cannot be made to appear by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del at the Welcome screen twice. This makes it impossible to logon to a hidden user account while the Welcome screen is enabled (when Classic Logon is not enforced through Group Policy).

Therefore the answer to your question is **No.**